# How separate string, c#

Tags: c#, xml, string, youtube

I have a problem with getting a 'keyword' from this string, i tried string.replace() but it didn't work, has anyone any idea, how separate keyword from this string?

```
var url = "< id xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keyword< /id>";
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to know if it contains the 'keyword' then there is the `Contains()`function. If you want to split the string at the 'keyword' the you could try `Split()`

Comment: Please **do not** parse XML via string split/regex. There are plenty options in .Net Framework that deal with XML files/stream: `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you work with xml document, it will be easy to get values elements:

```
var xml = "<id xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keyword</id>";
var url = XElement.Parse(xml).Value;

var index = url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var keyword = url.Substring(index);
```

If you always need just last segment you can easily achieve with Url instance:

```
var keyword = new Uri(url).Segments.Last();
```

Thanks @Alexei

Comment: +1. Using `Uri`/`UriBuilder` and `Path.xxxx` to extract last segment of Uri would be nice professional touch to the answer :)

Comment: I agree with @Alexei, `new Uri(url).Segments.Last()` will be nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better and cleaner way to this but this should work:

```
string keyword = url.Substring((url.IndexOf("videos/")) + 7,url.Length - url.IndexOf("< /id>")+1);
```

Or this:

```
string keyword = url.Substring(83, url.Length - url.IndexOf("< /id>") + 1);
```

Comment: @MNie since a `string` is immutable, you must place the result of a `substring()` method in a new `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var url = "< id xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keyword< /id>";
            string[] splitArra = url.Split(new  char[]{'/','<'});
            string keywordString = splitArra[11];
```